# Problem with MongoDB @Query annotation/Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I got problems with @Query annotation or `Query query = new Query()` - I can't include/exclude some fields.

I find code samples like:

```
@Query(value = "{'id': ?0}",fields = "{'id':1}")
User findUserById(String id);
```

Result should be user with only one field -> id but its showing other fields to..

So I found other samples like:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("id");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
User one = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class);
```

Same result there..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer findUserById(String id);
```

Use the DataType of Id [like Integer] to get only id.

Change datatype of according the requirement/usecase

Comment: But its still not a solution, your code will map full data object to specific DataType/Object with required fields - but still you requesting for all data from database